# ag-grid gridOptions.api undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying ag-grid in angular2 with typescript, for some reasons I am not able to use the ag-grid APIs, getting undefined error.,

**here is the code:**

```
import { AgRendererComponent } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import { GridOptions, RowNode } from 'ag-grid/main';
import { GridOptionsWrapper } from 'ag-grid/main';
import { GridApi } from 'ag-grid/main';

public gridOptions: GridOptions;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
constructor()
{
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

    alert(this.gridOptions);
    alert(this.gridOptions.api); // *** getting undefined  ***
    
    
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs(),
        rowData: this.rowData,
        onSelectionChanged: this.onSelectionChanged,
        groupSelectsChildren: true,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,

        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        rowHeight: 45}
    
}
```

Please advise, Thanks

**Updated with code in comment below**

```
onGridReady() {
    console.log(this.gridOptions.api); // here it work
    this.selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(this.selectedRows);
}

private testClick(event): void {
    try {
        console.log(this.gridOptions.api); // here gives error
        this.selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
        console.log(this.selectedRows); //getting error saying undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Two issues...

First ,as others have mentioned, initialise a reference to the grid api in onGridReady like so

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
}
```

Secondly, when ag-grid calls one of your provided handlers (E.g. rowClicked), `this` is no longer your angular component instance, so in your `testClick()` method `this.gridOptions === undefined`.

To access properties of your angular component in an AgGrid Event callback you should pass `this` via `GridOptions.context` like this:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
     context: {parentComponent: this},
     ...other lines
```

AgGrid's events (generally) return a reference to this context object in the Event params..

```
rowClicked(rowClicked: RowClickedEvent) {
    const localGridApiRef = rowClicked.context.parentComponent.gridApi;

    // do stuff with the grid api...
    const selectedRows = localGridApiRef.getSelectedRows();
};
```

Note: I'm not sure how you used `testClick()` but my `rowClicked()` would be interchangeable I expect...

**Note 2** - The `GridApi` is actually a property of `RowClickedEvent`, so while getting it via the context object as shown is superfluous, it illustrates the point that accessing properties/methods of your angular component in an ag grid event can be done via `AgGridEvent`'s `context` property.

Comment: This one is correct, when I get GridApi from params on onGridReady callback then it's fine

Answer (score 7):

The `gridOptions` api will be set and ready to use once the grid's `gridReady` event has been called.

At the line you're testing for it, `gridOptions` is just an empty Object, and even after you do this:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
     columnDefs: this.columnDefs(),
     ...other lines
```

It still won't have the api available - hook into the `gridReady` or angular's `ngOnInit` events and you'll be able to invoke the api safely.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.,  

  onGridReady() {
      
        console.log( this.gridOptions.api); // here it works
        this.selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
        console.log(this.selectedRows);
    }
    private testClick(event): void {

        try {
             console.log( this.gridOptions.api); // here gives error

this.selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
            console.log(this.selectedRows); //getting error saying undefined 
}

please help me out on this interesting issue

Comment: When does testClick get called? Is it user driven?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I can run this in onGridReady or even ngOnInit and still API is  undefined ;c

Comment: Same here, on AngularJs 1.x; I define my grid options filed `onGridReady` to be a function, and, when it is called, the API is undefined :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's because of component lifecycles. In `constructor` it's not initialized yet. (I'm assuming you assigned gridOptions object to your grid properly.)

Try using it in

```
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log(this.gridOptions.api)
}
```

From the documentation

> ngOnInit   Initialize the directive/component after Angular first
>   displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's
>   input properties.

Get more info about lifecycles [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-purpose-timing).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer on this while using AngularJS. For anyone else who ends up in the same issue as me (though it was not an AngularJS specific issue), I found that I was not calling the table correctly in the HTML. Since the table was never being called, the api was never getting set up and gridReady was never running. Syntax I used that worked:

```
<div class="table-body">
  <div ag-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="ag-theme-fresh ag-grid-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  selected = () => console.log('ID: ', this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[0].id);

  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: 'ID', field: 'id', width: 80},
        { ... }
    ],
    rowSelection: 'single'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions.rowData = this.gridData;
    this.gridOptions.onSelectionChanged - this.selected;
  }
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was using vue.js
Had same issue.
But when I included
:gridOptions="gridOptions" in my ag-grid-vue component
that solved my problem