# ag-grid API Undefined in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using the ag-grid API in an Angular 2 app, inside the ngOnInit method.

In the onGridReady event [like mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395466/ag-grid-gridoptions-api-undefined-in-angular-2), the API is accessible and things work fine.

However, I need to call the API in one of the following methods as well:

- onRowDataChanged
- onNewColumnsLoaded
- onModelUpdated

This is not working because the API is undefined. In addition, for some reason I can also call the API in the onCellDoubleClicked and onCellClicked events.

This seem to be a bug. Does anyone know what is going on?

Please see the code bellow:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{

        onGridReady: function (param) {
            param.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); // works fine
        },

        onCellDoubleClicked: function (param) {
            param.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); // works fine
        },

        onRowDataChanged: function (param) {
            param.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); // API is undefined
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples

Comment: You can see my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/44094147/2372205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is how I got it working.

- First, capture the this reference for your angular component just to make sure that you will not have JavaScript scoping issues.
- Then, capture the API reference when it is available inside the onGridReady event
- Lastly, only call the API after the stack is empty, deferring all the API calls with the setTimeout function

So now the code looks more or less like this:

```
...
let self = this;
...
onGridReady: function (param) {
    self.api = param.api;
},

onRowDataChanged: function (param) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        self.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
        ...more API calls...
    }, 0);
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is an issue, `ag grid` will not create `api` properly, so `api` will be `undefined`.

In my case, there was an error in console about i forgot to import `'ag-grid-enterprise'` (i was using `rowModelType: 'serverSide'`), so it fails to init.

So check if the options are valid and if it gives you any error on console.