# AG Grid - Best way to access to the GridApi

Tags: ag-grid

Which is the cleanest way to access to the GridApi of the AG Grid:

Option1

```
import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridNg2;
```

Option2

```
Event onGridReady
```

Comment: Option 2 will make sure to capture the API reference when it is available  and option 1 doesnt guarantee API availability ,as it's might not be initialized sometimes

Comment: So the best way is Option2. I see also more 'correct' this way

Comment: in some scenarios ,  most common error for api is undefined , check this linkf or more details -

Comment: which link? I think you forgot to paste the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348472/ag-grid-api-undefined-in-angular-2

Comment: sorry forgot to paste it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `onGridReady` function and use `params.api` to assign by your `property`