# How to change agrid data in parent?

Tags: angular

I have parent component where i call child component. Child component is `ag-grid`. What i want is to send data from parent component to child component every time and to display that data in `ag-grid`. This is my plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/2uHs2SwQfpH56DN9Tjjd?p=preview

This is my data in parent component:

```
  data:any;
  changeData(){
      this.data = [
            {"row": "Row 1", "name": "Michael Phelps"},
            {"row": "Row 2", "name": "Natalie Coughlin"}
        ];
  }
```

And this is how i send data from parent to child:

```
<ag-filter-component [data]="data"></ag-filter-component>
<button (click)="changedata()">CHANGE DATA</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Plunker**
[LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/PZjgqyUjIwZ0EOqCSaMK)

```
import {Component,Input,OnChanges} from '@angular/core'; // imported onChnges to listen to the changed button click

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   console.log(this.data); // can view the updated data when you click CHANGE DATA check console for changing data
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData = (this.data) ? this.data : this.createRowData(); // this is not working reason mentioned below

 }
```

**Reason**

[git Issues](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-angular/issues/105).

There is no way i was able to update the grid after value change which is the only thing needed now check this SO question [ag-grid gridOptions.api undefined in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395466/ag-grid-gridoptions-api-undefined-in-angular-2).

> Now only thing remains is inside ngOnChanges in child component we need to refresh the
>   grid

This is not the complete answer but it is a issue now with agrid hope it helps.

Comment: when i click change data nothing happend

Comment: check the console . i have updated the reason why its not happening

Comment: ngOnChanges on chid component or parent component?

Comment: Child component

Comment: Were you able to refresh the grid? If so please update in comment